# Angular2 Observable.map capture value of local variable

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

How can one capture *value* of a local variable for use inside `Observable.map()` callback? For example, in my Anglar2 application I would love to capture *value* of `quantity` for use in `findItem().map()`:

```
let quantity : number = 1; //<-- needs to be captured
let ordered : string[] = [];
//not interested in actual results, just adding queried items to cart
let queries : Observable<void>[] = [];
//res.entities are NLP classified entities, either item_id:string or quantity:number
for (let entity of res.entities) {
    if(entity.entity == 'item') {
        queries.push(
            this.findItem(entity.value).map(item => {
            if(item != null)
            {
                for(let i : number = quantity; i > 0; i--) this.cart.addItem(item);
            }
            ordered.push(quantity + 'x ' + item.fullName);//NL message for user
        }));
        quantity = 1;//reset quantity
    }
    else if(entity.entity == 'quantity') quantity = entity.value;
}
return Observable.forkJoin(queries, ...);
```

The `ordered` will show quantity 1 for all items (because value of `quantity` is always 1 at the end of the loop). 
My research shows that this is very common problem in JavaScript, and there are plenty of examples how to capture a variable in `for` loops. I wasn't able, however, to find any information how to capture variable values for use in *callback*s, such as `Observable.map()`

Comment: use a `const` instead - `let` will not exist after the function scope has ended.

Comment: @DanielCooke isn't `const` nonassignable(also, compiler complains)? If there is "quantity" recognized, the variable should be assigned (next "item" should have the quantity). Or should I introduce another `const` variable in `if(entity.entity == 'item')` scope?

Comment: @DanielCooke yes! introducing anothe variable in the `if`s scope `if(entity.entity == 'item') { const lq = quantity; ... }` produced expected results - please consider adding it as answer to this question.

Comment: yes , apologies for the vagueness. I have added it to the answer

Comment: Isn't this what a `BehaviorSubject` is for?

Comment: @Jeff that might as well be - with my limited experience in js apps I know only little portion of Observables API, but I will gladly learn how to do what I tried to do properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a const within your `for` loop.

```
for (let entity of res.entities) {
    if(entity.entity == 'item') {
        const q = quantity; //here or somewhere
        queries.push(
            //..... use q instead
    }
    else if(entity.entity == 'quantity') quantity = entity.value;
}
```